# WPF: Scrollviewer doesnt work once explorer is killed. How to do it?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have a WPF application on windows tablet. So, it doesnt have keyboard and hence as soon as we tap on editbox in my application, the onscreen keyboard appears and the page shows vertical scrollviewer by placing the textbox at the centre. It happens because of the following code I have written.

```
private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() != typeof(ScrollViewer))
            return;

        var sv = sender as ScrollViewer;

        if (sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            var focusedControl = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
            if (focusedControl == null)
                return;

            if (!textFieldIsCentered && focusedControl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                var textbox = focusedControl as TextBox;

                ScrollViewerPositioner.CenterTextFieldInScrollView(textbox, sv);
                textFieldIsCentered = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textFieldIsCentered = false;
        }
    }
```

But my application also needs to kill explorer.exe on windows 7 bootup itself. So i have a .bat file which runs on windows startup and kills the explorer and launches my application by default without letting the user to go to desktop. This is very much needed as tablet should only restrict the user to see my application only.

Now when I kill explorer and tap on editbox, the scrollviewer doesnt appear. Hence, editbox which is in bottom of page gets hidden behind on-screen keyboard. This implies explorer has some part in doing this centering in scrollviewer.

What i want to know is, is there a way to achieve what i want even after killing the explorer ??

Comment: No answers fr this ? :(

Comment: Create your own keyboard.